# Program compiles, but won't run

Tags: java, jframe

Let's keep it simple. My code compiles, and when I run it (using `java CLASSNAME`), this is my command prompt error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is
decorated
        at java.awt.Frame.setBackground(Frame.java:986)
        at RPG.<init>(RPG.java:147)
        at RPG.main(RPG.java:69)
```

For reference, this is the code at line 147

```
    Map.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

And the code at line 69

```
    Game.setContentPane(new RPG());
```

They are two different JFrames, but they are conflicting?
Here is the entire snippet from my source:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
  }
  catch (Exception unused) {  }
  Game.setTitle(" ");
  Game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Game.setContentPane(new RPG());
  Game.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
  Game.pack();
  Game.setSize(850,500);
  Game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  Game.setResizable(false);
} 
  public RPG(){
    sgame = 1;
    Game.setVisible(false);
    JFrame Map = new JFrame();
      Map.setTitle("Map");
      Map.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Map.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
  Map.setUndecorated(true);
  JLabel testLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Title.png")));
      Map.add(testLabel);
      Map.setSize(200,200);
      Map.setLocation(0, 250);
      Map.setResizable(false);
      Map.setVisible(true);
    Launcher();
  }
```

Sorry if it seems unclear or if I am not making much sense, I'd just like to know why I can't launch my program.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `Map` as Undecorated before you call .setBackground().

Comment: WOW, that worked just fine. Would you mind telling me why setting background before setting undercoated causes the program to crash?
Are you able to explain that for me?

Comment: Think of it like a book. Java will execute the code in the order it is presented. When you first create the new frame (JFrame Map = new JFrame();), you create a new frame entirely that is, albeit, decorated. When you try to set the background on it, it errors because the frame is decorated. Because .setUndecorated(true) is after .setBackground(), the events happen in the wrong order.

Comment: Thank you.
Knowledge for the future :)